# Yii2 Sort multiple parameters URL

Tags: yii, yii2

I have an endpoint in yii2 where I need to sort by multiple parameters. Im using ActiveDataProvider. This is the enpdoint:

```
public function actionIndex($client) 
{
        $sort = new Sort([
            'attributes'=> ['name','mail','crdate']
        ]);
        $query = Customer::find()
                ->andWhere(['client' => $client])
                ->orderBy($sort->orders);
        $provider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);
        return $provider->getModels();
}
```

Now sorting by a single parameter as in: **customers?client=1&sort=mail** works fine.

I want to sort by multiple parameters though. How should I do this in the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set

```
$sort = new Sort([
    'attributes'=> ['name','mail','crdate'],
    'enableMultiSort' => true,
]);
```

Now you can pass multiple sort column by separating them with `,` like

```
?sort=name,mail
```

If you prepend name with `-` you get descending order otherwise it's ascending.
If you want to change `,` separator to something else set it in `separator` configuration key for Sort object.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try search model for Costumer model

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Costumer::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([some condition for search]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```